# Client Status: Can't connect to server

Tags: smartfoxserver

I have set up an SFS 2X server on the LAN and server-side OS is Mac OS X.. I am trying to host this (http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesUnity/object-movement) Unity 3d game (provided as an example) on the server that is accessible through the web browser across the LAN. But I am getting an error. [image]Screen shot is attached.

-- I am making sure that I am entering the correct server-side IP address and port in the "ConnectionGUI.cs" script (that comes with the example).

PS, I am able to run administration utility on other computers on the LAN besides my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the SmartFox server running on the same computer? Or a different one?

If it's running on a different one, make sure it's listening to its external IP address (not 127.0.0.1) and check if the firewall is allowing traffic through 9933.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Solved my problem long ago, The sample project do from SFS have IP as public var so you can also edit this variable from Unity3d, I was the IP in script but haven't reset the script from Unity3d, Thats why it was getting localhost IP.